# Passing XML and Outputting to Twig Template in SlimPHP 3

Tags: twig, slim, slim-3, guzzle6, twig-extension

Currently using the SlimPHP 3 MVC framework and trying to XML output of a URL to the Twig template. I'm using the latest build of Guzzle if it helps.

I have my Controller set up and the function as follows:

```
public function getaws($request, $response, $args) {
    $bucketname = $args['bucketname'];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $bucket = $client->request('GET', $bucketname . '.s3.amazonaws.com');

    if($bucket) {
        $buck = $bucket->getBody();
        return $this->view->render($response, 'aws.twig', ['buck' => $buck]);
    }
    else {
         $res = Array();
         $res['message'] = 'Bucket Disabled or Unknown';
         return $this->view->render($response, 'aws.twig', ['buck' => $res]);
    }
}
```

In the Twig file - aws.twig I have only been able to output the entire XML response/body using:

```
{{ buck }}
```

I have tried typing:

```
{{ buck.Name }}
```

or

```
{{ buck.Key }}
```

Neither have worked. I've tried the ForEach loop as well and nothing comes from that at all. I'm completely at a loss. I've noticed that there doesn't seem to be an awful lot of help on SlimPHP but I like it and prefer using it to Laravel and no I won't switch to Laravel just to make life easier otherwise asking for help with this would be a waste of time.

Anyone who has had experience with SlimPHP 3, Twig templates and Guzzle - I'd very much like help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `buck` a pure string? If so then you can't traverse it before converting it to something like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: It seems like that is the case since `{{ buck }}` seems to echo out the entire XML output. Unfortunately when I tried feeding it into SimpleXML it didn't like it.

Comment: Perhaps you have better luck with [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: @DarkBee Yes as it happens between comments here using the `simplexml_load_string()` function worked a treat, however now I've got a table output with five blank rows before outputting the rest of the XML.

Comment: @DarkBee Nevermind I have sorted that issue. Your suggestion of using `simplexml_load_string()` function worked perfectly so thank you!